# How to obtain package name of an application in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I want to display package name of an application in a `BroadcastReceiver` whose `intent` is received in that `receiver`. I used the `intent.getPackage()` method but it is not working. I also tried to display that package name using context object which is a parameter of `onReceive()` method to display package name but it is not working.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This way :

```
ApplicationInfo packageInfo = this.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
```

EDIT : This is not working from a broadcast receiver, I misread the question.

Reading this page : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
Intent.getPackage doesn't give you the package that called but the one that the intent is limited to.

If I understand this page clearly, Intents do not provide the package name or anything allowing you to identify it.

If you are the one sending the intent(but I believe you are not), you could send the package name in the intent in a parcelable that you'd be able to retrieve in your broadcast receiver. Otherwise, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Thanks.But I am intercepting intents like outgoing phone calls in a class which is extending BroadcastReceiver and in onReceive() method of that class I want to print the name of package of an application that has sent the intent like outgoing phone call. Thats why I used intent.getPackage() method but it is returning null value.

Comment: Sorry about that I misread your question. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks. But I didn't understand the term "package name the intent is limited to". Is there any other way like obtaining activity name or process name of that intent? For outgoing phone calls I am just getting phone no. but I want to retrieve some additional information also.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345"));
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
ResolveInfo info = pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
System.out.println("Package Name[Call]:- " + info.activityInfo.packageName); This code is displaying package name of built in dialer application and used the same for received intent in my broadcast receiver but it is not working.

Comment: This will not work : resolveActivity finds the best package to process the intent. It does not retrieve the activity that launched the intent. As far as I know Intents do not carry by default any information about the activity that triggered it.

Comment: Can anyone answer this question please because I have the same problem and I post my question as "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420767/monitor-currently-running-application". But there is no reply. So please reply ASAP.
Cheers!

Comment: @Renegade : This has nothing to do with your question. The reason why nobody answered you in your thread is because your not doing your part : Code + Error message.