# Monitor Currently Running Application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am encountering a problem that i can't not solve for the moment.
The purpose of the code is to monitor which applications are running at current moment.
I used the following code and logged the resulting package name, it worked.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();  
Log.i("TTWYMonitor", packageName);
```

But I use that code in a `BroadcastReceiver`, nothing happened.
In `manifest`,I declared an intent receiver `android:name=".MonitorApplication.`
What should I do, then?
Please give any suggestion.

[Yahel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578746/yahel) : Thanks and sorry for my informal question.

Comment: Logcat of the error and your code plz

Comment: ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );   <<<<<  I use that command and it's not working in BroadcastReceiver. That's why. My question may be funny but be patient and reply me.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant piece of code in your question and the error message that your code generates. Edit your question by clicking on the "edit link" below its text.

Answer (score 0):

replace the "Activity" in getSystemService's parameters with "Context":

```
ActivityManager  manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

I tested it and works fine for me!