# Android how to know which application is opened at any instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-activity

In my application i want to show a message using BroadcastReceiver, but i want it to display the toast message only when the application is not opened and currently running on the screen (it may be running in the background). But i am not finding the exact code to implement the condition accordingly.

I have tried the code,

```
    ActivityManager manager = 
        (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

but it stop the message when running another application also.

Please help how i can make my code aware about whether the application currently opened or not? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SendBroadcast if Activity or Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865687/sendbroadcast-if-activity-or-notification)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420767/monitor-currently-running-application

Answer (score -1):

With credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service), and, by extension, cyanogenmod 7.

You're halfway there. RunningAppProcessInfo has a field called pkgList, a String[] that contains all the package names in the process, which you can match against to determine if it's your app.

```
private RunningAppProcessInfo getForegroundApp() {
    RunningAppProcessInfo result=null, info=null;

    if(mActivityManager==null)
        mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List <RunningAppProcessInfo> l = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator <RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        info = i.next();
        if(info.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
                && !isRunningService(info.processName)){
            result=info;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
```

}